# NodeJS code working in my pc but not in other pc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-web-developer

My code is running perfectly in my pc, but when I shared the code with my friend, it shows me an error "Operation users.findOne() buffering timeout".

Nothing was changed in the code, except the path of the root directory.

Comment: Is your friend's program connected to a running MongoDB server?

Comment: Yeah it's connected

Comment: On your friend's computer, can `mongosh` successfully execute `db.users.findOne();`?